# Checking/Verifying Proof for all $a,\,b\in N$, $a|b$ if and only if $bZ\subseteq aZ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Prove that for all $a,\,b\in\Bbb{N}$, $a\mid b$ if and only if $b\Bbb{Z}\subseteq a\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer: = Since $a|b$ $\implies b=ax$ for some $x \in\Bbb{Z} \implies b=ax\in a\Bbb{Z}$

Therefore, $b\in b\Bbb{Z} \implies b\in a\Bbb{Z}$ thus $b\Bbb{Z} \subseteq a\Bbb{Z}$.

Conversely,

Suppose $b\Bbb{Z} \subseteq a\Bbb{Z}$ then in order to show $a|b$ let $x \in b\Bbb{Z} \implies x=b\cdot y$ for some $y\in \Bbb{Z}$ ; at $y=1$ you have $x=b\in a\Bbb{Z} \implies a\cdot k$ for some $k\in \Bbb{Z} \implies a|b.$

So because $b\in a\Bbb{Z}$, there exists $x\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $b=ax$ thus meaning that $a|b$.

Is my answer all correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the second part because you don'w know that $x/y$ is an integer. An alternative is to argue that as $b  \in b\mathbb{Z}$, then $b \in a\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore...

Comment: The second part is wrong.  "$q = by$ for any $y\in Z$" means that $q = b*1$ and and $q = b*7$ and $q = b*349$ and ... obviously this is wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for feedback. Is my new solution better?

Answer (score 1):

1. The opening statements
   $$a\Bbb{Z}=\{a\Bbb{Z};\ \text{ for any }\ x\in\Bbb{Z}\}
    \qquad\text{ and }\qquad
    b\Bbb{Z}=\{b\Bbb{Z};\ \text{ for any }\ y\in\Bbb{Z}\},$$
   do not make any sense.
2. You write

   > However, as $a$ divides $b$
   >
   > $\implies$ $b=ax$ for any $x\in\Bbb{Z}$.

   This is false; it should be $b=ax$ for *some* $x\in\Bbb{Z}$.
3. Next you write

   > $\implies$ $p\in a\Bbb{Z}$ therefore $x\in\Bbb{Z}$, $y\in\Bbb{Z}$ $\implies$ $xy\in\Bbb{Z}$.

   This the wrong way around; *because* $xy\in\Bbb{Z}$ you have $p\in a\Bbb{Z}$.
4. You write

   > Now take $b\Bbb{Z}\subseteq a\Bbb{Z}$. As $b\Bbb{Z}\subseteq a\Bbb{Z}$ then for any $q\in b\Bbb{Z}$ then $q\in a\Bbb{Z}$ therefore $b\Bbb{Z}\subseteq a\Bbb{Z}$.

   This is a pointless tautology.
5. The remainder of the proof makes no sense. In stead, argue that *because* $b\in a\Bbb{Z}$, there exists $x\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $b=ax$. This means precisely that $a\mid b$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is this solution better?

Comment: Since $a|b$ $\implies b=ax$ for some $x \in Z \implies b=ax\in aZ$

Therefore, $b\in bZ \implies b\in aZ$ thus $bZ \subseteq aZ$.

Conversely,

Suppose $bZ \subseteq aZ$ then in order to show $a|b$ let $x \in bZ \implies x=b\cdot y$ for some $y\in Z$ ; at $y=1$ you have $x=b\in aZ \implies a\cdot k$ for some $k\in Z \implies a|b.$ 

So because $b\in aZ$, there exists $x\in Z$ such that $b=ax$ thus meaning that $a|b$.

Answer (score 0):

In the first part:

⟹p∈aZ therefore x∈Z,y∈Z⟹xy∈Z

is backwards.  You don't conclude $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $y \in \mathbb Z$ from $p \in a\mathbb Z$.

You conclude that because $p = a(xy)$ and because $xy$ is an integer (because $x$ and $y$ are both integers so $xy$ is too) that $p\in a\mathbb Z$.

But otherwise 1) is good.

2) however is a complete mess.

"Now suppose bZ⊆aZ. As bZ⊆aZ then for any q∈bZ then q∈aZ therefore bZ⊆aZ."

This is completely circular and unnecessary.  This is like saying: Suppose Henry is a carnivore.  As Henry is a carnivore then Henry eats meat and therefore Henry is a carnivore.

Instead just state: "Suppose $a\mathbb Z \subset b\mathbb Z$. Let $q \in a\mathbb Z$.  therefore $q \in b\mathbb Z$."

You say: ⟹q=ax for some x∈Z. But aq∈bZ

THis is weird. Why are you working with $aq$ instead of just $q$.  Yes $aq \in a\mathbb Z \subset b\mathbb Z$ but $aq$ is not relevent.  Or was that a typo and you meant but $ax \in b\mathbb Z$?

⟹q=by for any y∈Z.

I think you meant that $q = by$ for *SOME* integer $y$.  Obviously $q =by$ for *ANY* $y\in \mathbb Z$ is an absurd and false statement.  That would mean $q = b*1=b$  and that $q = b*513= 513b$ so $q = b = 513b$.  That's only true if $b=q = 0$.

But maybe you meant to say:  $q =by$ for some $y\in \mathbb Z$.

"Therefore, q=by=ax and b=a(x∣y) for all y≠0"

Is $(x|y)$ supposed to be $\frac xy$?  It is true that $b = a \frac xy$ but we have utterly no reason to assume $\frac xy$ is an integer.

If you meant $x$ divides $b$ then this statement is "$b$ equals $a$ times $x$ divides $y$" which isn't even in English.

You need work.  Notice if $b = 5$ and $a = 4$ and you have $40 = 5*8 = 4*10$.  That does not mean that $4|5$.

You need to work with the idea that for *ANY* $bx \in b\mathbb Z$ there is *some* $ay\in b\mathbb Z$ so that $bx = ay$.  So for *every* $x$ there is *some $y$ so that $bx = ay$.  You need to prove that means $a|b$.

You need to do *more* than $a = b\frac xy$.  You need to use that $x$ may be *any* integer.

Hint:  $b= b*1 \in b\mathbb Z\subset a\mathbb Z$ so......

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I edited my solution above.